# writing script for sftp winsshd

Tags: sftp

I want to transfer text file over sftp (winSSH server).  how can I do it?  I realize that I need to write script and run with windows scheduler. is there any example?  pls guide me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read a step by step guides how to:

- [write file transfer script using WinSCP (SFTP client)](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) and
- [schedule file transfers to SFTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*